# Android Room error: Schema '1.json' required for migration was not found at the schema out folder

Tags: android, migration, android-room, database-migration

I want to implement autoMigrations with Android Room

```
@Database(
    entities = [User1Message::class],
    version = 2,
    autoMigrations = [AutoMigration (from = 1, to = 2)],
    )
abstract class User1MessageDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
```

I also add this code in gradle

```
kapt {
    arguments {
        arg("room.schemaLocation", "$projectDir/schemas")
    }
}
```

But error message says that not found.
[image]

`1.json` is in folder already

[image]

How to solve it?

UPDATE:
`User1MessageDatabase` has only `2.json`
how to auto generate `1.json`?
[image]

Comment: That `1.json` is for the `User1ChatroomDatabase`. The error is complaining about the `User1MessageDatabase`.

Answer (score 3):

> how to auto generate 1.json?

Revert the code to version 1, then add the `exportSchema = true` and then compile the project. Move to version 2.

Comment: Thanks. But I did not add this attribute, schema can still be generated sometimes. Why?